# How to call a javaScript Function

Tags: javascript, namespaces

I have a function `onChangeBrand()` in *A.js* and there is a same name in *B.js*.

So how to avoid this situation? There is a constraint - I can't change the function names.
and  i am not allowed to edit both the Js files so namespace is not a right idea for me.

Can we call something like `A.onChangeBrand()` or `B.onChangeBrand()`?

Comment: Are you able to put your js code on the page between the `script` tags loading these files?

Comment: Yes @Cherry i am taking them in my src

Comment: My nickname is slightly different. And the second question - do these functions have calls from those files or only you are using them?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Java.  Please ***read the description*** of tags applied to posts.

Comment: @Cheery, those are part of some API .So apart from me other guys are also using them.

Comment: @AbhisekBose  I meant another thing. Read it in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, if namespaces are not for you and you can put your code in between the `script` tags loading these files

```
<script src='a.js'></script>
<script>
var a_onChangeBrand = onChangeBrand; // copy the function
</script>
<script src='b.js'></script>
```

after that `a_onChangeBrand()` will call the function from a.js and onChangeBrand() from b.js

But nothing will help you if some functions in those a.js and b.js are also using these functions - they might call function from the last file loaded.

Comment: This is Something out of the box thought. Thanks @Cheery

Answer (score 1):

Check how to use namespaces in JavaScript if you can edit these two files a.js and b.js then you can declare namespaces. See best answer here : [How do I declare a namespace in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881515/javascript-namespace-declaration)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access to the source, then the following is a solution (not the prettiest, mind you):

```
<script src="http://exmpale.com/a.js"></script>
<script>
 A = { onChangeBrand:onChangeBrand };
</script>

<script src="http://exmpale.com/b.js"></script>
<script>
 B = { onChangeBrand:onChangeBrand };
</script>
```

The two functions are now namespaced and can be invoked like so:

```
A.onChangeBrand();     
B.onChangeBrand();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to one of your function..

```
var myNS = new (function() {

    this.onChangeBrand= function() {
        alert('hello!');
    };

})();
```

and then call `myNS.onChangeBrand();`

Similarly use myNS2 for other function. These are called as namespaces.